# Elasticsearch Update by Query using CTX

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to update all documents inside the the index. I found that Update Query is the method we should use. But, I am facing problem when I am using ctx._now as a value for updated document's field, causing the field value become null.

This is the sample:

```js
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.timenow = ctx._now"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

[image: timenow evidence]

When I am using random number value, it is work. Let say that I put timenow = 5. Then, All documents field timenow become 5. But, it is not work using this ctx method.

How should I do that ?

**Additional Information**

This is my ES information:

```js
"version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.1",
    "build_hash" : "19c13d0",
    "build_date" : "2017-07-18T20:44:24.823Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  }
```

I am using ctx._now because it is work on document update. Here are the case:

```js
{
  "script": "ctx._source.timenow2 = ctx._now"
}
```

Example: POST index/type/24/_update

Here is the docs from elastic:

> In addition to _source, the following variables are available through the ctx map: _index, _type, _id, _version, _routing and _now (the current timestamp).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html

Thank You

Comment: where did you see `ctx._now`? What version of ES are you using?

Comment: If all of your timenows are being updated to null, that means `_now` is not a field on `ctx`.  What made you use `_now` (where you find information about it)?  Try setting the `timenow` values to be `Instant.now()` or something like that to see how that works.

Comment: I have update my question adding ctx._now. How can I use Instant.now() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_now` is only available in the Update API, i.e. when you call the `_update` endpoint, not `_update_by_query`.

Use this instead:

```
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.timenow = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, which is faster Instant.now or new Date().getTime() ? I found new Date().getTime() on other site.

Comment: The fastest is `System.currentTimeMillis()` which is what `Instant.now()` uses underneath

Comment: Hi, i have tried and it works so well. Thank you so much

Comment: Unfortunately, on Elastic 5.4.1 in my painless script I get: "Unknown call [now] with [0] arguments on type [Instant].". I don't see any now() in [api reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference.html) for painless. Probably will have to pass timestamp as parameter to the script.